# Array index into column in AngularJS using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need help in getting JSON array index into table columns using AngularJS ng-repeat. Below is the JSON and I want to convert it to a HTML table:

```
{
  "Employee": [
    {
      "Name": "`Rocky`",
      "Location": "Office"
    },
    {
      "Name": "John",
      "Location": "Home"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Rocky</td>
            <td>John</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Office</td>
            <td>Home</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: var obj = JSON.parse(text);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="list in object.Employee">
          <td>{{list.Name}}</td>
          <td>{{list.Location}}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8699/

Answer (score 1):

Just use like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in obj.EmpArray">
    <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.Location}}</td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: This doesnt work I was getting
Rocky Office
John Home

Thanks for quick answer!!

Answer (score 0):

To access the array key using ng-repeat, do the following:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
  <td> {{key}} </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This doesnt work I was getting Rocky Office John Home Thanks for quick answer!!